# How to get VoiceOver to announce section labels in iOS?

Tags: ios, voiceover

In the iPhone Weather App, when using VoiceOver, I noticed that tapping into a section for the first time, it will announce the section.

For example, in iOS 9, tapping on any item the middle strip for the first time will announce "Hourly forecasts" before continuing to describe the element you tapped on. Tapping anything else in the strip will not announce "hourly forecasts".

Tapping on anything on the bottom table, will announce "Daily forecasts" before continuing to describe the element you tapped on. Tapping anything else in this table will not prefix with "Daily Forecasts".

Is there a simple API to name sections of your app? Or do you have to do this manually by tracking the voiceover cursor and dynamically changing your label? (Does this even work? Can you change the accessibilityLabel after something is tapped but before it is read?)

Comment: You could use a UIGestureRecognizer to detect touch on whichever UIView you wanted, use a boolean to indicate weather you have announced something, and use AVSpeechUtterance to announce what you want.

Comment: @thealienisreal I came here with the exact same question. Did you ever have any luck with this?

Comment: @djibouti33 No luck. Lots of answers on general accessibility implementation, but none that solve this particular scenario.

Answer (score 2):

There are two approaches I guess:

1. Subclassing the UITableViewCell and overriding the accessibilityLabel.

   ```
   - (NSString *) accessibilityLabel
   {
       NSString* voiceOverString;
       // append section title on voiceOverString and then the elements value
       return voiceOverString;
   }
   ```
2. See this link from [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW5):
   You can setAccessibilityLabel of the cell from cellForRowAtIndexPath. The example is for the weather app itself.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a simple API to name sections of your app?

It seems like the most appropriate reference is [Apple's Accessibility Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iPhoneAccessibility/Making_Application_Accessible/Making_Application_Accessible.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008785-CH102-SW5).

And its API, [Apple's UIAccessibility Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAccessibility_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSObject/accessibilityNavigationStyle).

Setting the `shouldGroupAccessibilityChildren` property seems like the best way to accomplish your goal. The linked API describes it as,

> > A Boolean value indicating whether VoiceOver should group together the elements that are children of the receiver, regardless of their positions on the screen. Setting the value of this property to YES on the parent view of the items in the vertical columns causes VoiceOver to respect the app’s grouping and navigate them correctly.

**Things to keep in mind:**

1. **Is the target element an accessibility element?** (you can check using the `isAccessibilityElement` property; standard UIKit controls and views implement the UIAccessibility protocol by default)

   - If so, you just need to set its accessibility attributes
   - If not, you need to change its value, `view.isAccessibilityElement = true`
2. The `accessibilityLabel` property identifies the element
3. The `accessibilityHint` property describes the action triggered by an element
4. You can set accessibility attributes in the storyboard
5. Or, you can set accessibility attributes in the implementation of your view subclass

Comment: `shouldGroupAccessibilityChildren` property only affects the order that the VoiceOver cursor navigates the elements, but this boolean value does not provide a way to name the section. You describe the way to label the elements, but I'm looking for a way to announce the section name when tapping any element before announcing the element itself within the section for the first time the section gains focus, just like the weather app does.

Comment: Did you set the `isAccessibilityElement` property of your containing view to `true`? If you do that and group it with the children elements, that might solve it.

Comment: It's possible that Apple's Weather app functions as you mentioned because it contains custom elements in a container view. "A container view, on the other hand, contains other elements with which users can interact. For example, in a custom subclass of UIView that performs its own drawing of geometric shapes, the shapes represent elements with which users can interact, and which are distinct from the container view. Such separate elements within a container view are not automatically accessible (because they are not subclasses of UIView)." This method might automatically announce the section.

Comment: You also have to make sure the child elements are not modal. If a view is modal, VoiceOver "ignore the elements within views that are siblings of the receiver." For example, "In a window that contains sibling views A and B, setting accessibilityViewIsModal to true on view B causes VoiceOver to ignore the elements in the view A. On the other hand, if view B contains a child view C and you set accessibilityViewIsModal to true on view C, VoiceOver does not ignore the elements in view A." [API](https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/nsobject/1615089-accessibilityviewismodal)